# Imitate Select Behavior with Button in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app that uses Bootstrap 3. I have a drop down list that is currently defined like this:

```
<select id="options" class="form-control">
  <option>Go home</option>
  <option>Go Left</option>
  <option>Go Up</option>
  <option>Go Right</option>
  <option>Go Down</option>
</select>
```

I like the behavior of the drop down list because when you choose an option, its text is shown. I also like the fact that the drop down stretches to fill the available space. However, I want the dividers that [Bootstrap's button drop downs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) provides. In an effort to get the best of both worlds, I've attempted the following:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Go Home... <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Go Home</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Go Left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Go Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Go Right</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Go Down</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I choose an option, the text does not get updated though. In addition, the drop down does not stretch to fill the available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `btn-block` class to make the buttons and dropdown fill width..

```
   <div class="btn-group btn-block">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Go Home... <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Go Home</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Go Left</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Go Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Go Right</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Go Down</a></li>
              </ul>
   </div>
```

The only way to get the dropdown to behave as a select control is using JavaScript and/or jQuery like this..

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/KI7AAEtWeo